# Does NativeLoader supported on Windows?

Tags: windows, hadoop, apache-spark

I have build Hadoop 2.7.3 from source, all succeeded. I am using a prebuild Spark 2.0 binary with Hadoop 2.7 support. When I start the spark-shell, I got this warning.

```
16/09/23 14:53:24 WARN NativeCodeLoader: Unable to load native-hadoop library for your platform... using builtin-java classes where applicable
```

`hadoop checknative -a` gives me

```
16/09/23 14:59:47 WARN bzip2.Bzip2Factory: Failed to load/initialize native-bzip2 library system-native, will use pure-Java version
16/09/23 14:59:47 WARN zlib.ZlibFactory: Failed to load/initialize native-zlib library
Native library checking:
hadoop:  true D:\hadoop-2.7.3\bin\hadoop.dll
zlib:    false
snappy:  false
lz4:     true revision:99
bzip2:   false
openssl: false build does not support openssl.
winutils: true D:\hadoop-2.7.3\bin\winutils.exe
16/09/23 14:59:47 INFO util.ExitUtil: Exiting with status 1
```

Do I have to get native build for all the libraries? I checked the Hadoop build instruction, and I could not find any information about build the other libraries.

Or maybe there's some miss configuration in my Spark. But I could not figure out what. I have these environment variable set for my Spark:

```
set HADOOP_HOME=D:/hadoop-2.7.3
set HADOOP_CONF_DIR=%HADOOP_HOME%/etc/hadoop
set SPARK_HOME=D:/spark-2.0.0-bin-hadoop2.7
set HADOOP_COMMON_LIB_NATIVE_DIR=%HADOOP_HOME%/bin
set SPARK_LOCAL_IP=
```

Comment: you have to build it with zlib-dev to get zlib support